# Execution order of useEffect in combination with updating state

Tags: reactjs

Given the following simple component:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  useEffect(function a() {
    // Do stuff
    setState("Some value");
  }, [])

  useEffect(function b() {
    // Do stuff
  }, [state]);

  // return some fancy JSX
}
```

The execution order will be:

1. `MyComponent` mounts and `MyComponent()` executes and returns JSX.
2. function `a` is executed and the state change gets queued.
3. function `b` is executed (The state change from 2) is not yet reflected, so `state === ""`).

Now my question is, given that `state` might change by other triggers than drafted here, is there any guarantee that the `setState("Some value")` from function `a` will have happened by the time the effect `b` is executed the next time (after step 3) above)?

In other words, may there be any constellation where `b` will be called because `state` has changed, but the `setState("Some value")` from `a` has not happened yet?

Comment: The initial rendering also triggers function `b` which `setState("Some value")` is not applied yet

Comment: Yes, see 3) in the original question.

Comment: In my opinion this will never happen because state will only be declared if the component mounts, and if the component mounts useEffect will always run.

Comment: `setState("Some value")` will run only once on mount so no. And even on mount, yes `a` runs first, but at the time `b`is  running the value set in `a` with `setState("Some value")` has not picked up as a re-render is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very possible.
Here's the demo:

```js
function Home() {

  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  useEffect(function a() {
    // Do stuff
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState("Some value");
    }, 10000);

  }, [])

  useEffect(function b() {
    // Do stuff
  }, [state]);

  // return some fancy JSX
  return <>
    <button onClick={() => setState('this is executed first')}>

      hello

    </button>

    <h1>{state}</h1>
  </>

}
```

The state will update as soon as you clicked the button and then changed again after 10 seconds (from function A)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really think it applies to my question. My function `a` does the state update synchronously, while you artificially delay the update by wrapping it in a `setTimeout`.